# Solution to safe with six keys, largest number of people with 3 different keys each.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

A safe has six locks. A group of people each receive a different set of three keys to the safe. Any two people should not be able to open the safe, due to missing at least one key. What is the largest possible number of people for which this is possible?

My solution:

> $n$ is the number of people in the group, which is equal to the number of different sets of keys. Let's number the keys 1-6, and give person$_1$ keys, $[1,2,3]$. There are two ways we can go here, but both yield the same result. All other people must share one key with person$_1$, and have two keys that person$_1$ does not have, so the number of sets of keys is equal to ${3\choose1}\cdot{3\choose2}$, or all other people must share two keys with person$_1$, and have one key that person$_1$ does not have, so the number of sets of keys is equal to ${3\choose2}\cdot{3\choose1}$. You can not have both of these at the time, or else there would be groups of 2 people that could open the safe. ${3\choose1}\cdot{3\choose2}=9$, plus person$_1$ equals $10$.

Is my solution correct?

Also, what tag should this be? I'm not sure what area of math this would fall under.

Comment: The sentence "Any two people should not be able to open the safe, due to missing at least one key." is not clear to me, but I think it should be combinatorial design theory.

Comment: I added combinatorics, would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ unique 3-combinations of the six keys--therefore it's not possible to distribute unique groups of three keys to more than 20 people.  At a minimum, we can always just distribute less than six of the keys to get $\binom{5}{3} = 10$.  This is the number of 3-combinations that can be made by removing any one of the 6 keys--which means there are 6 different sets of 10 3-combinations each missing a different one of the 6 keys.  So we only need to investigate one--because they should all be symmetric under renaming.

It shouldn't be surprising that this cuts the initial number in half.  For each of the remaining 10 key groups (each containing, say k1) there is *exactly* one key group in the other half (none of which contain k1) which will combine to give all 6 keys.  What this means is that it is *not* possible to add anymore 3-combinations without at least two people having all 6, distinct, keys.

If the question is that you *must* distribute all keys (i.e. at least some set of people can open the safe), then you can still do it with 10 key groups by simply taking one of the remaining key groups containing k1 and swapping it out with its complement (the group with the other three keys).  It is not possible for this new group (containing k1) to combine with any other combination to make a complete set.

So you can do it with 10 people:

1. k1 k2 k3
2. k1 k2 k4
3. k1 k2 k5
4. k1 k3 k4
5. k1 k3 k5
6. k1 k4 k5
7. k2 k3 k4
8. k2 k3 k5
9. k2 k4 k5
10. k3 k4 k5

Now choose any combination including k6--say--k1 k2 k6.  The complement to this is k3 k4 k5--so swap it out to get:

1. k1 k2 k3
2. k1 k2 k4
3. k1 k2 k5
4. k1 k3 k4
5. k1 k3 k5
6. k1 k4 k5
7. k2 k3 k4
8. k2 k3 k5
9. k2 k4 k5
10. k1 k2 k6

Comment: What tag should I have put this under?

Comment: @Bretsky I don't know...combinatorics certainly seems important.  I don't know what else would have been relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $10$, however, your solution seems not complete, I suggest the follow solution.

Let $S:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We search for a family $\mathcal{K}$ of subsets of $S$ with $3$ elements such that there is no disjoint pair of elements in $\mathcal{K}$. Note that, if $K\subseteq S$ is in $\mathcal{K}$, then $S\setminus K$ is not in $\mathcal{K}$. Hence, we have $|\mathcal{K}|\leq\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{2}=10$. Moreover, we can take $\mathcal{K}:=\{K\subseteq S:1\in K,|K|=3\}$ which has $10$ elements. Hence, the answer is $10$.